# Submitting PDF form to a PHP page

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF form and I'm trying to submit it to a PHP page. The form submits as:

Data submitted via HTTP POST (content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded):

```
þÿ = afdaquadi
```

Raw HTTP POST data:

```
%fe%ff%00t%00o%00p%00m%00o%00s%00t%00S%00u%00b%00f%00o%00r%00m%00%5b%000%00%5d%00.%00P%00a%00g%00e%00
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @Dagon It's supposed to return the form inputs something like this:
TextField1:
TextField2:
RichTextField:
ListBox1:
RadioButtonList:
Raw POST Body
65 bytes:
TextField1=&TextField2=&RichTextField=&ListBox1=&RadioButton

But it's not

Comment: But the raw data you have quoted say *topmostSubform[0].Page* which surely is the start of the hierarchical name of a field. UTF-16 and %xx byte encoding...